# What Causes ORA-38910 error

Tags: oracle

I have a script which reads from XML and tries to execute the SL present in it on the database.
But I am getting the error ORA-38910 when I execute the select commands on the database.
The odd thing is the script sometimes works and sometimes does not. Also it works with smaller batches than with the entire population.

So I was hoping to learn what causes the Oracle error : `ORA-38910: BATCH ERROR mode is not supported for this operation.`  The Oracle documentation I read on this errors, were unfortunately not very helpful for me.

Comment: What is the query you are running?

Comment: The most common cause of this is `FORALL ... INSERT` statement with both the `/*+ APPEND */` and the `SAVE EXCEPTIONS` clause.  Which is most likely a bug.   If that doesn't fit your circumstances you'll need to show us the statement(s) which give(s) you this grief.